# How to make a image a clickable link in html and css?

Tags: html, css

For example, while searching in google image in the search logo is clickable and forwards to the search item. how to  that ?

I don't know how to implement.

Comment: Wrap the [<img>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img) tag within [<a>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a)

Answer (score 0):

The  and the  tags together can add the image in the Html and CSS.
In a webpage, after adding an image using the  tag, make it clickable by adding a  tag along with it.